# logging not logging from modules

Tags: python-3.x, logging

I've been at it and all over my code, and perhaps am blinkered by it.

Following setup in my `__main__.py`:

```
if args.debug:
    logpath = '{}/ganalytics_mf70.dbg'.format(backend.utilities.get_module_path())
    lvl = logging.DEBUG
else:
    logpath = '{}/ganalytics_mf70.log'.format(backend.utilities.get_module_path())
    lvl = logging.INFO


log = logging.getLogger('GAnalytics')
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s: %(name)-12s: %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
fh = logging.FileHandler(logpath) # file logging
fh.setLevel(lvl)
fh.setFormatter(formatter)

formatter = logging.Formatter('%(name)-12s: %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
ch = logging.StreamHandler()  # console logging
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
ch.setLevel(logging.INFO)

log.addHandler(ch)
log.addHandler(fh)
```

All other .py files have

```
import logging
log = logging.GetLogger(__name__)
```

at the top.

package outline:

```
program/
    - backend/
        - foo.py
        - bar.py
        - spam.py
        - __init__.py
    - __main__.py
```

This logs all `log.debug` and higher calls in my `__main__.py` - but none of the `log` calls in `spam`, `bar`, `foo` or `__init__` py files.

Where's the glaringly obvious mistake I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the other modules live under a top-level package (read: subdirectory of something listed in [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path)) named GAnalytics, they won't go through the logger you have configured in `__main__.py`, and so their log events below WARNING will be dropped by default.

Most of the time, you want to make changes to the root logger, which is given by [`logging.getLogger()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.getLogger) (with no arguments, or with argument `None`).  This is most easily accomplished with [`logging.basicConfig()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig), but you can do it manually as well.

(Side note: You probably don't want to call a module `__main__.py`.  `import __main__` *always* means "import the main module" (that is, the module that Python was invoked with) and never "import a file named `__main__.py`," so if it ever happens that `__main__.py` is not actually the main module, you will be very confused by the resulting behavior.  Files with that name also cannot use the standard `if __name__ == '__main__':` guard because that condition is always true.)

Comment: Oh wow. I didn't think you can't just toss any name into GetLogger(). #whenskimreadingshootsyouinthefoot.